# Using SerialPort.Write(string) through DSharpPlus returns System.NullReferenceException. Literally what is wrong here?

Tags: c#, string

I've been getting System.NullReferenceException whenever I tried sending a string called "woah" which has a value of "1" to a SerialPort.

I've been trying to turn on my LED light through that but it's just not working! I tried changing serialport settings or maybe directly sending "1" through it but it just doesn't work. The error is at

```
_serialPort.Write(woah)
```

Please help:
Here's the code.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using DSharpPlus;
using System.IO.Ports;

        namespace OngCorptHubert{class Program{
    
        static SerialPort _serialPort ;
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
                MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
            _serialPort.Open();
            }
    
    
    
        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var discord = new DiscordClient(new DiscordConfiguration()
            {
                Token = "nuh uh",
                TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
                Intents = DiscordIntents.AllUnprivileged
            });
            discord.MessageCreated += async (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Message.Content.ToLower().Contains("?led-ong"))
                {
                Console.WriteLine("Trying to send message to port.");
                    string woah = "1";
                    _serialPort.WriteLine(woah);
                    Console.WriteLine("Successful!");
                 await e.Message.RespondAsync("LED should be on");
                }
                
                
    
            };
            await discord.ConnectAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }
        
    }
    }`
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the serial port before to write in it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. What do you mean by opening it like,
serialport.open()

Comment: @McNets how would I do that?

Comment: I think I know what you meant by that @McNets . Do you mean to put _serialPort.open() right before writing it? If so, then I'm afraid to say it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

OH MY GOD I found the problem!!
I don't know how but I think I just badly initialized the SerialPort.
I removed `static SerialPort _serialport;` and removed `_serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None,8,StopBits.One); _serialPort.Open();`
And instead I added `SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); _serialPort.Open();` right before the writing command.
My LED has turned on, I love programming.